# How to config npm to search exported modules?

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I use `npm` in my client side development.

I use `ES6` and I import modules to `mapApp.js` file from library that I installed in `node_modules` folder with help of `npm` tool.

Here is how I import module to `mapApp.js` file:

```
import GML from 'ol/format/GML';
```

Where is 'ol/format/GML' is relative path to node_modules folder.

At some point I create my own module(in `config.js` file) outside of node_modules folder and I need to import it to `mapApp.js` file.

Here is picture of project architecture:

[image]

My question is how can I config `npm` to make search for imports not only in node_modules folder but, also in specific folder outside of `node_modules`?

Comment: have you used require(X) from module at path Y

Comment: @SachinYadav can u explain what do u mean?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together